# How do I display the main domain for my WordPress install?

Tags: php, redirect, domain, hosting

I have a WordPress installed in a subfolder. To access it, my URL is this:

```
www.web.site/myfolder
```

However, what I want to do is to get access to my site directly just by using my domain like this:

```
www.web.site
```

Without using `/myfolder`. I've tried to move my files from `/myfolder` to `root`, but I encountered some problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave your WordPress site where it is in `/myfolder` and follow these steps to easily access the website by going to `www.web.site` instead:

1. In your **Dashboard** go to *Settings > General*
2. In the **Site Address (URL)** remove the `myfolder` where you installed WordPress
3. Click *Save Changes*

it should look like the following example:

[image: Website URL]

However, if you want to move your WordPress files to the `root` instead of `myfolder`. You'll need to do the update the links your database after you move your Wordpress files to the `root` of your host. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://web.site/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. Enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Comment: i tried this solution on a test website and it ruined it, now i can't access to any page, can you please tell me what is your second solution

Comment: @MessiAdrinho Updated answer